# Hyperparameter tuning with tensorboard HParams Dashboad does not work with custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, hyperparameters

I got a custom keras Model which I want to optimize for hyperparameters while having a good tracking of whats going on and visualization. Therefor I want to pass hparams to the custom model like this:

```py
class Model_hparams(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super(Model_hparams, self).__init__()
        self.hps = hparams
        
    def build(self, inputs_shape):
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=self.hps[HP_NUM_UNITS_1], 
                                            kernel_size=self.hps[HP_LEN_CONV_1], 
                                            activation='relu', 
                                            input_shape=inputs_shape[1:])
        self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        # actually, here are even more layers
    def call(self, x, training=True):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        return x
```

I followed [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams) from TF:

```py
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api as hp
HP_NUM_UNITS_1 = hp.HParam('num_units_1', hp.Discrete([16, 32]))

HP_LEN_CONV_1 = hp.HParam('len_conv_1', hp.Discrete([3]))

METRIC = 'mae'

with tf.summary.create_file_writer("../../model_output/hparams").as_default():
    hp.hparams_config(
    hparams=[HP_NUM_UNITS_1, 
             HP_LEN_CONV_1,],
    metrics=[hp.Metric(METRIC, display_name='Test_MAE')],
  )

def run(run_dir, hparams):
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
        hp.hparams(hparams)  # record the values used in this trial
        test_mae = train_model(hparams)
        tf.summary.scalar('Mean_Average_Error', test_mae, step=1)
```

Now my training fuction calls the model with my training procedure which looks like this (simplified):

```py
def train_model(hparams):
    model=Model_hparams(hparams)
    
    for batch in dataset:
        #...
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(batch, training=True)
            #...
```

The actual optimization starts here:

```py
n=0
for num_units_1 in HP_NUM_UNITS_1.domain.values:
    for len_conv_1 in HP_LEN_CONV_1.domain.values:     
        hparams = {HP_NUM_UNITS_1: num_units_1,
                   HP_LEN_CONV_1: len_conv_1}
        run_name = "run-%d" % n

        run("../../model_output/hparams/" + run_name, hparams)
        n += 1
```

However, if I run this, an error occures when I want to instantiate my model:

```py
<ipython-input-99-17dd66300f5b> in __init__(self, hparams)
     72     def __init__(self, hparams):
     73         super(Model_hparams, self).__init__()
---> 74         self.hps = hparams
     75 
     76     def build(self, inputs_shape):

c:\users\123\anaconda3\envs\python_3_8_env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
    312         isinstance(v, (base_layer.Layer,
    313                        data_structures.TrackableDataStructure)) or
--> 314         base_layer_utils.has_weights(v) for v in nest.flatten(value)):
    315       try:
    316         self._base_model_initialized

c:\users\123\anaconda3\envs\python_3_8_env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in flatten(structure, expand_composites)
    339     return [None]
    340   expand_composites = bool(expand_composites)
--> 341   return _pywrap_utils.Flatten(structure, expand_composites)
    342 
    343 

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'HParam' and 'HParam'
```

I´m not sure why this happens and I cannot get it to work. I cannot find anything in the docs.
Is there anything I´m missing??
Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.Model` class overrides `__setattr__` function, so you can not set mismatched variables. However, you can bypass this function below trick.

```py
object.__setattr__(self, 'hps', hparams)
```

.. instead of

```py
self.hps = hparams
```

```py
class Model_hparams(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, hparams):
    super(Model_hparams, self).__init__()
    object.__setattr__(self, 'hps', hparams)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! 
Just for my interest, could you explain what exactly "mismatched variables" mean?
As stated in the [guide on how to write custom Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#best_practice_deferring_weight_creation_until_the_shape_of_the_inputs_is_known) , I can give additional parameters like `units` into to the `__init()__` and assign them with `self.units=units`. Whats the difference here?

Comment: @Crysers `__setattr__` function uses `tf.nested.flatten` that returns a flat list from a given nested structure. The function could not process `HParam` that argument is not valid for it